# Get supported resolutions without opening camera on Android

Tags: android, camera

Is there any option to get supported resolutions on old Camera Api(Camera 1) without calling `open()` method?

Comment: Old Camera API? Version? Anything specific?

Comment: @PraveenKumar there two APIs at Android: Camera and Camera2